Looking for comprehensive documentation for Solidity-generated bytecode
I'm currently working on analyzing the bytecode of smart contracts generated by Solidity. While examining the bytecode, I've encountered various opcodes and structures that I need to understand in detail. I've searched through the official Solidity documentation but couldn't find an in-depth guide on the specifics of the generated bytecode.
Is there any comprehensive documentation or resource that explains the bytecode generated by Solidity, including the meaning and structure of the opcodes, the separation between init code, runtime code, and metadata, and any other relevant details?
Any pointers or links to such resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This documentation might be helpful. As well as, this one.

This Article series explains it pretty well. Especially the 2nd and 3rd part

Here are some information/resources that could definitely help

To get an overall understanding of how bytecode is generated and works:
a. EVM article Part 1 and EVM Article Part 2
For a detailed list of EVM Opcodes ( along with their significance and gas ) - EVM.CODES
Init Code & Runtime code explainer - Rareskill EVM Article
Detailed list of additional EVM resources: EVM Resource Article

Hope this helps, feel free to ask more questions if need be.
